# Erratic behaviour with InStrRev when supplying start position

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I don't understand the results of any of the below. I understand InStrRev gives position of last 'matches' (right-to-left) & can comprehend the result when I don't give a start position. No matter if the start begins at left or right, 1 or 2 should give something other than 0.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim TestString As String
TestString = "ABCDEFGHCIJK"
msgbox = InStrRev(TestString, "C", 1) 'produces 0 if optional start parameter is 1 or 2
msgbox = InStrRev(TestString, "C", 3) 'produces 3 if start parameter is 3-8
msgbox = InStrRev(TestString, "C", 9) 'produces 9 if start parameter is 9-12
'13+ produces 0 as expected since its length of string is only 12
End Sub
```

Microsoft documentation on function: [access](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/instrrev-function-HA001228858.aspx) & [visual studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2ekk41a%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). On the visual studio page I tried the example at the bottom of the page & got same result, so I know its working. However my brain isn't getting. I also understand the InStr function with & without a start position

Comment: HansUp: may I ask why you removed vba tag in your editing?

Comment: Sure, from meta.stackoverflow my understanding is that we are encouraged to use the more specific application-vba tag instead of the general vba tag.  See the guideline at the tag wiki: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/vba/info  That said, I don't see this as a major issue, and if you prefer to add it back I won't change it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll offer a different example which I hope makes the situation clearer.  In the Immediate window (go there with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> shortcut) ...

```vb
TestString = "123456789"
? InStrRev(TestString, "3", 2)
 0
```

That statement asked `InStrRev` to start from the second character in `TestString` and search backwards for the character *"3"*.  Since the first two characters of `TestString` are *"12"*, *"3"* is not found in that substring, so `InStrRev` returns 0.

In this example, I ask `InStrRev` to start searching from the fourth character ...

```vb
? InStrRev(TestString, "3", 4)
 3
```

Since the first four characters of `TestString` are *"1234"*, *"3"* is found as the third character, so `InStrRev` returns 3.

Regarding the statement *"1 or 2 should give something other than 0"* ... that is not true, as my first example demonstrates.

Comment: Oh, I think I get it! See the start position is not really a start position for the whole string. Example: in your first example I thought it would search whats left: 3456789 & thus would produce 1 or 3 if it still includes the characters before the start position; bad name choice in my opinion. As you noted its searching the substring of which start tells it to grab the # of characters from the left ("12" in our case)

Comment: OK, seems you expected `InStrRev()` to use *start* as `Mid()` does ... `Mid("123456789", 4)` would return the substring *"456789"*.  Unfortunately, that is not what *start* means with `InStrRev()`.  ;-)  Cheers, Hans.

Comment: See I think my confusion was because I compared it to InStr & many online sites did as well. Example: `InStr(2, TestString, "3")` returns 3. I am speculating this works based on my original logic: it would search whats left: 3456789 & thus produced 3 as it still includes the characters before the start position. Whereas a _start_ of 4 produces 0

Comment: The return value is the character position (if found) in the original string, regardless of where within the string you ask the function to begin its search.  That is true for both `InStr` and `InStrRev`.  However, I'm doubtful whether my followup comments have helped clarify this thing.  So I think I'll stop.  ;-)

Comment: You affirmed my second thought. I still don't understand why `InStr(2, TestString, "3")` returns 3 if it follows the same logic as `InStrRev` being _start_ pulls substring _"12"_ & _"3"_ is not found it should return 0

Comment: `InStr(2, TestString, "3")` says to start its search at the second character in `TestString` ... so in my version of `TestString`, it searches these characters: *"23456789"*.  And it finds *"3"* as the second character it examines, which is the 3rd character in the *original* string.  So it returns 3.

Comment: So `InStr` with a _start_ position removes that amount of characters from the left side of the string before doing the search (from the left) on the remainder of the string. Whereas `InStrRev` with a _start_ position **retrieves** (a substring) that amount of characters from the left side & searches (from the right) that substring. I apologize this is dragging on, I am seriously not just messing with you; I cannot seem to grasp these concepts

Comment: Not exactly as I see it.  `InStr` begins its search at *start* position, but it doesn't first remove anything from `TestString`.  I don't suspect you're messing with me.  I think you're blocked on this one ... I've experienced that many times ... and I'm frustrated trying to find a way to make this brilliantly clear for you.  Oh well, fortunately God created beer.  Cheers.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

OMG I just got it! I am terrible, I have a tendency to over-think things. The below is what I think I got hung up on & some documentation didn't explicitly clarify:

- **Both functions** *start* **position begins on the left**
- **The return value is the character position (if found) in the original string, regardless of where within the string you ask the function to begin its search**

I couldn't have figured this out without [HansUp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15929177/1940218). Hopefully the below is another way to look at it in case anyone else has the same issue understanding:

- The below returns 5. Before A, the position is 1, before B 2 & so on. We told it to start at before C & search remainder of string (CDEFGHIJKLMN) which did have E in it still

  `InStr(3, "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN", "E")`
- The below returns 0. We told it to start at before C & search remainder of string (AB) which did not have E in it. The reason the remainder of the string was on AB was because it searches from RIGHT-TO-LEFT

  `InStrRev("ABCDEFGHIJKLMN", "E", 3)`

Comment: Aha, *"start position begins on the left"*; it didn't occur to me to clarify that point.  I'm pleased you got unblocked.  :-)